# Problem with richfaces a4j:jsFunction

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="accountGroup" layout="pagedirection" 
   value="#{xxx.accountGroup}" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px;" 
   onclick="selectAllAccountGroup(this.value);fireAjax();">

   <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Select All" />
   <f:selectItems value="#{xxx.userGroup}" />

   <a4j:jsFunction name="fireAjax" action="#{xxx.groupChanged}" 
     ajaxSingle="true" reRender="accountNumbersOp" process="accountGroup">
   </a4j:jsFunction>

</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Above is a list of check-boxes with select all option, if select all is selected all check-boxes are selected. On the basis of selected values I have to populate another check-box list, whose logic is in action method. I am facing few issues.

1. If I remove process attribute of tag "a4j:jsFunction", action method is called but I don't get the updated value of check-boxes list in action method.
2. If I use process attribute of tag "a4j:jsFunction", action method is called twice, Why So?
3. Even actionListener fails to solve the issue.

Any suggestions how can I accomplish this in a better way.

I am on jsf 1.2, richfaces 3.3.3, weblogic 10.3.2(Portal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with placing a4j:jsFunction outside h:selectManyCheckbox, it shouldn't be nested inside.